# Find index of 2d array in a 3d array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to find a 2d array in a 3d array. for finding a 1d array in a 2d array I can use `np.where(np.all(a==b, axis=1))[0][0]`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> a = np.array([[[1, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0]],

                  [[0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0]]])
>>>
>>> b = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0]])
>>>
>>> a.find(b)
0
```

Comment: It's almost the same. You just need to use the proper axis and maybe use another `all` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `axis` keyword accepts tuples, so you can simply do:

```
np.where(np.all(a==b, axis=(1, 2)))[0][0]
```